# Download a JSON array without any objects in the array, and add to a autocompletetextview

Tags: java, android, json

I am working on an app that downloads a series of strings from an api, then places them in an array so that they can be called from an autocomplete textview field. I am having trouble downloading the array however. The array is just `["String", "String" ... etc]` I am using ASyncTask to call the api and download the json, but I cannot figure out how to download it correctly... Thanks for your time...

**MapFragment.java**

```
package com.horizonservers.horizon;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MapFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MapFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private TextView test2;
    AutoCompleteTextView textView;
    ArrayList<String> Maps = new ArrayList<String>();

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MapFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MapFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        new PostDataTask().execute("https://www.horizonservers.net/api/mentions/maps?q=surf_&c=map");


        textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Maps);
        textView.setThreshold(3);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
        test2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.testMap);

        return v;
    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    class PostDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                return postData(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return "Network error !";
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                return "Data Invalid !";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {


              JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    final JSONArray e = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
                    String name = e.toString();
                    Maps.add(name);
                }

                test2.setText(Maps.toString());





                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Horizon", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to load maps.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }


        private String postData(String urlPath) throws IOException, JSONException {

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

            try {
                //Create data to send to server
                JSONObject dataToSend = new JSONObject();
                //Initialize and config request, then connect to server.
                URL url = new URL(urlPath);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);  //enable output (body data)
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");// set header
                urlConnection.connect();

                //Write data into server
                OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
                bufferedWriter.write(dataToSend.toString());
                bufferedWriter.flush();

                //Read data response from server
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line).append("&");
                }
            } finally {
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
                if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                }
            }

            return result.toString();

        }

    }



}
```

really the part that is calling the JSON is OnPostExecute which is

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {


              JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    final JSONArray e = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
                    String name = e.toString();
                    Maps.add(name);
                }

                test2.setText(Maps.toString());





                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Horizon", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to load maps.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Also it should be noted that this array has no objects, just strings and I guess the problem I am having trouble with is setting to a textview **for right now** just so that I can see it has downloaded. I try and convert it to a string but I get `org.json.JSONException: Value Network of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

use this function to connect to web server

```
private HttpURLConnection connection;
private URL url = null; 
public void connect()
{
    try {
        url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.connect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and then use this function to get string from there

```
public String getStringFromServer()  {
    InputStream input;
    StringBuilder result;
    String line,JSONRESPOND="";
    BufferedReader reader;

    try {
        input = this.connection.getInputStream();
        reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        result= new StringBuilder();
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            result.append(line);
        }
        JSONRESPOND = ""+result.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       return null;
    }

    return JSONRESPOND;
}
```

finally make this

```
connect();
String yourJSON = getStringFromServer();
JSONArray yourArray = new JSONArray(yourJSON);
```

you can parse this array using this snippet

```
ArrayList<String> yourParsedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i =0; i<yourArray.length();i++){
 yourParsedStrings.add(yourArray.getString(i));
}
```

Comment: This did not work. It gives no errors but doesnt display the text just the same as the one I have

Comment: Where you are setting text ?

Comment: To see that it has downloaded?

Comment: if you are trying to see if it has been downloaded then you can just use `Log.d("TAG",yourParsedStrings.get(0)` or loop through them (iteration variable instead 0)

Comment: what is your problem again can you clarify that? actually the code above works perfectly. After downloading this string from your webserver you just need to parse it. so you create jsonarray and then extract values into arraylist. from this array list you can create listview (or autocomplete textview)

Comment: No it doesn't work. If you run your code either in its own section or run it onPostExecute it throws a JSONException error everytime. It's okay though I just downloaded the JSON. I'll figure it out later. Thanks!